# Parsed results in UITableView

Tags: html, ios, parsing, uitableview

I am using HTMLParser by Ben Reeves. It works great but the only problem is that I couldn't put the output in UITableView.  Anyone can tell me what's wrong with this code? ...................................................................................

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://website.com/"];
    NSString *strin=[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    HTMLParser *parser = [[HTMLParser alloc] initWithString:strin error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        return;
    }

    HTMLNode *bodyNode = [parser body];
    NSArray *divNodes = [bodyNode findChildTags:@"div"];

    for (HTMLNode *inputNode in divNodes) {
        if ([[inputNode getAttributeNamed:@"class"] isEqualToString:@"views-field-title"]) {
           NSLog(@"%@", [inputNode allContents]); 

           listData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[inputNode allContents], nil];   
        }
    }      
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return [self.listData count]; 
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: SimpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row]; 
    cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row];

    return cell; 
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer as to what you want to happen? How do you want to present the HTML data in the table?

Comment: I want to have a list of events in UITableView but tableview shows me only the last one of the array. I treat [inputNode allContents] as an array and trying to put it in "cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row]". In the console, it shows me the list of events, but I see only the last event in the cell. I might be missing something. Don't know what...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reinitializing your array every time you find a new element. I think you need to move

`listData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[inputNode allContents], nil];`

outside of your loop and change it to

`listData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

`listData` should be an `NSMutableArray` so you can add data to it. You'll need to change this in your variable definition too.

Then inside your loop, use `[listData addObject:[inputNode allContents]];`

Comment: @Benjamen Excellent. Glad to hear it! :)